# Is it possible to reverse engineer a ROM chip by grinding and taking photos?

Tags: physical-design, rom

Recently someone made a claim that you can reverse engineer a ROM by physically grinding the chip and taking pictures of the various layers.

Is this really possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a ROM that stores its data in physical features (a mask ROM, or a fuse ROM, both very old types) this should be possible. I can't imagine it being possible for an EPROM/EEPROM/FLASH ROM, which store data as very small charges.

For a RAM/ROM that is based on magnetics (stone-age core memories, magneto-resistive, bubble memory, ...) you might be able to blow very fine iron particles over it and deduce the content from the pattern that they form. Might make a good shot for a movie..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your additional comment definitely sounds like something that belongs in a movie! But if it ever does happen at least this answer can help satisfy the no doubt countless hoards of doubters. :)

Comment: Note that I said 'might'. Maybe there is not enough magnetics 'leaking' from such store, or the particles would be too large, or .... But Cameron can always email me for advice :)